# Problema al capturar un dato por procedimiento almacenado SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy trabajando con esta tabla en SQL Server 2014:

```
create table suceso 
(
  id int identity (1,1) not null,
  codMod varchar (10) not null,
  fecha date not null
  constraint pk_suceso primary key (id)
);
go
```

Y este es el procedimiento almacenado:

```
create procedure sp_insNuevoModulo
@codMod varchar (10)
as
begin 
  declare @fecha date;
  set @fecha = (select fecha from suceso where codMod = @codMod and fecha = 
  (select convert (varchar(10), GETDATE(),103)));
  if (@fecha = null)
     insert into suceso values (@codMod, (select convert (varchar(10), GETDATE(),103)));
end
go
```

En resumen, si es que el retorno llega a ser nulo, tendría que agregar un dato nuevo, caso contrario, nada.

cuando ejecuto:

```
 exec sp_insNuevoModulo 'COD01';
```

me aparece el mensaje: "Comandos completados correctamente."
pero al consultar la tabla está vacía.

Comment: Creo que estas colocando esto mal `if (@fecha = null)` prueba sin paréntesis de  de esta manera: `if @fecha is null begin .... end`

Comment: Muchas, pero muchisimas gracias, ahora sí está guardando los datos de forma correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver el problema solo debes cambiar en el Stored Procedure esto: `if (@fecha = null)` por esto: `if @fecha is null` , ya que esto `@fecha = null` es prácticamente una asignación y no una pregunta.

```
  create procedure sp_insNuevoModulo
    @codMod varchar (10)
    as
    begin 
      declare @fecha date;
      set @fecha = (select fecha from suceso where codMod = @codMod and fecha = 
      (select convert (varchar(10), GETDATE(),103)));
      if @fecha is null 
      begin 
         insert into suceso values (@codMod, (select convert (varchar(10), GETDATE(),103)));
      end
    end
    go
```

Saludos!